# Ruby `unless` not working

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am learning Ruby at the moment and I have written the below code, however it is causing errors when running.

The idea is that a channel will only be inserted in to the database if it is not already present in the database (checked via `exists?` method).

```
def exists?(channel)
    rs = @con.query("SELECT * FROM channels WHERE name = #{channel}")
    return true unless rs.empty?
end

channels.each do |channel|
    @con.query("INSERT INTO channels (name, timestamp) VALUES ('#{channel}', '#{Time.now.to_i}')") unless channel.exists?
```

Here is an error message shown once I include this code:

> undefined method `exists?' for "#channel1":String

Is there an error in the code that I've written?

Comment: It depends on what `channels` is. Looks like an array of strings from here. Strings don't have `exists?` defined inside.

Comment: Sorry, what's `channels` got to do with it, I am checking a single `channel`?

Comment: Exactly, `channel` comes from `channels`.

Comment: Don't use `"SELECT * FROM channels WHERE name = #{channel}"` if you only want to know if any exist. Imagine what the DBM will do if there are thousands of records, you'll get them all, wasting CPU and network IO because you immediately throw away the result. Instead do a [`count(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) and you'll get back one value which is the number you're looking for. Then use `rs > 0` instead of the entire `return` line.

Comment: I had to use `n_rows = rs.num_rows` and then `n_rows < 1`, bit messy. `rs.empty?` would be neater.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about the syntax. If you want to use your above-defined method, you should have this:

```
@con.query("INSERT INTO channels (name, timestamp) VALUES ('#{channel}', '#{Time.now.to_i}')") unless exists?(channel)
```

Comment: Hmm, now I am getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`, something to do with the `exists?` method but it looks ok to me for the intended purpose ...

Comment: Time for some debug printing. You get error in sql query? Debug-print that and examine what actually gets generated.

Comment: My guess is that you're missing quotes around your `channel` interpolation. Or something like that

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev. Inside of your `exists?` method, in the assignment `rs = `  your string interpolation `#{channel}` needs to be enclosed in quotes for so that SQL will recognize it as a string. i.e. `WHERE name = '#{channel}'` instead of `WHERE name = #{channel}`.